# Python program don't run in container only when i call a function

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a python program that must run in a docker container. When I execute the program in my workspace the program run well. I made a custom Dockerfile from a python image, this image have the same packages in the same version that I have in my workspace. When I run the container using compose the container starts but when I call a specific function the program seems not to run. I put a print before this function call and the print works only when I comment the func call (the func call is after the print), when I call the function the print don't works.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-slim

RUN apt update \
    && apt upgrade -y\
    && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev libglib2.0-0 \
    && pip install redis==3.5.3 opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.32 imutils==0.5.3 scikit-image==0.17.2 \
    && mkdir src
    
WORKDIR /src

CMD ["python"]
```

My compose:

```
version: '3.1'  

services:  
  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    command: redis-server --requirepass 123
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  doorState-peopleCounter:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: custom
    volumes:
      - /media/jose/Arquivos/Argos/rasp-services/movementdetectionwindowsdoor:/src
    command: ["python", "Tracker.py"]
```

With this code the print doesn't works:

```
print('[INFO] - Iniciando monitoramento da porta')
tracking.count(source='videos/subindo.mp4')
```

When I comment the func call the print works:

```
print('[INFO] - Iniciando monitoramento da porta')
#tracking.count(source='videos/subindo.mp4')
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the logs of your container? What does `docker-compose logs doorState-peopleCounter` say?

Comment: Your compose file runs `python Tracker.py`; your Dockerfile only runs `python`.

Comment: The logs dosn' t show any errors

Comment: Dockerfile CMD is "python" but in the compose file I run "python Tracker.py". The program  only don't run when I call tracking.count()

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the container logs only show the prints of the program when the python program ends. So the problem was that I wasn't waiting the program finish and the i started to think that the program was not running.

Answer (score 0):

Change

> FROM python:3.8.5-slim

to

> FROM python:3.8.5

You can add regular python, not Slim, it may be large, but it will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This is python's output buffering. It's a performance feature. You can disable it with the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` or by running python with the `-u` flag.
You can also call print with the `flush` keyword argument.

```py
print('[INFO] - Iniciando monitoramento da porta', flush=True)
```

- [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering)
- [How to flush output of print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function)
- https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u